# How Do I prevent a constructor of a derived class from passing a variable to the base class?

Tags: c#, oop

Imagine owning a piece of land ( a new class) and to build a Rail Station on the land ( another class)
in oop what is the relationship between these two class?

Terrain or land class:

```cs
namespace Classes;

public class Terrain
{

    private string terrainName;
    
    public Terrain(string name)
    {

        this.terrainName = name;
    }


    public string TerrainName
    {
        get { return terrainName; }    

    }

}
```

Rail Station class:

```
namespace Classes;

public class RailStation : Terrain
{

    private string railStationName;

    public RailStation(string name): base(name)
    {

        railStationName = name;
    }

    public string RailStationName
    {

        get { return railStationName; }
    }

}
```

```
var station = new RailStation("newWorld");
```

```
Console.WriteLine($"Nuova Rail Station: '{station.RailStationName} station' and new Terrain '{station.TerrainName}'");
```

When I instantiate the RailStation Class , How Do I assign a name to the land and one to the Rail Station ?
For now , the code always prints the same name for the land and the house

EDIT : @Steve

I agree, it's a conceptual issue.

```cs
public class RailStation
{

    private string railStationName;

    public RailStation(string name)
    {

        railStationName = name;
    }

    public string RailStationName
    {

        get { return railStationName; }
    }

}

public class Terrain
{

    private string terrainName;
    public List<RailStation> RailStations { get; set; }

    public Terrain(string name)
    {

        this.terrainName = name;
    }


    public string TerrainName
    {
        get { return terrainName; }    

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var terrain = new Terrain("NewLand");
terrain.RailStations = new List<RailStation>();

var station01 = new RailStation("Station01");
var station02 = new RailStation("Station02");
var station03 = new RailStation("Station03");
terrain.RailStations.Add(station01);
terrain.RailStations.Add(station02);
terrain.RailStations.Add(station03);

Console.WriteLine($"Nuova stazione: '{station01.RailStationName} station' su nuovo terreno '{terrain.TerrainName}'");
Console.WriteLine($"Nuova stazione: '{station02.RailStationName} station' su nuovo terreno '{terrain.TerrainName}'");
Console.WriteLine($"Nuova stazione: '{station03.RailStationName} station' su nuovo terreno '{terrain.TerrainName}'");
```

Aggregation should be a better solution Thank you

Comment: If the two entities have different names then you need to provide two strings in the RailStation constructor. But, a RailStation derives from a Terrain? It doesn't seem to be correct. Perhaps a _Terrain has one or more RailStations_ seems more logical.

Comment: A rail station isn't terrain. Inheritance specifies an `is-a` relation and child instances should be usable everywhere a parent is. There's only one instance, not a parent and a child instance. It seems you're looking for composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi It should be aggregation and not composition because the stations are not fundamental to the terrain ?

Comment: @Giovanni did you just edit your question to provide its own answer?  Perhaps you should have submitted an answer to your own question as an actual *answer*, not as an *edit* to your question.

Comment: Consider having `RailStation` inherit from.`Building`. Then have a `Terrain` contain one or more `Plots` or `Lots`. Then finally have a `Plot` have 0 or 1 `Bulidings`. So in your case, you start with a Terrain, put a Plot on it, and have your RailStation be the Building on it. In object oriented design, you spend a lot of time describing real world things in terms of _"is a"_ and _"has a"_

Comment: @Flydog57 << ..you spend a lot of time describing real world things in terms of "is a" and "has a"..>> Okay, but I don't understand where you're going with this .Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Sure, there are tons of possible solutions; I merely proposed one. Sometimes, after you figure out an object oriented design, you come up with an implementation that does not mirror the design exactly. This is often because you want more dynamism or dynamic loadability, or any of the other non-functional _-abilities_. The point of what I was getting at was to reinforce what @PanagiotisKanavos said: "a rail station is not a terrain; a terrain may have a rail ststion"

Comment: Side note: you should use auto-properties `public string TerrainName { get; }` you can still set these from the constructor even though no setter is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved my program and read about the 'factory pattern,' which seems to suit my needs
I gladly accept further observations

```
using Classes;

 // create a container of type TerrainContainer to create various objects within it.
TerrainContainer world = TerrainFactory.CreateContainer<Terrain>();
// create a first terrain in TerrainContainer
world.AddTerrain(new Terrain("NewCity"));
// create a Building object within TerrainContainer
world.AddBuilding(new Building("RailStation"));
// create a Fruits object within TerrainContainer
world.AddFruits(new Fruits("Apple tree"));


// Example
// access the first terrain in the list.
ITerrain terrain = world.GetTerrain(0);
Console.WriteLine(terrain.Name);

// access the first Building in the terrain object.
IBuilding building = world.GetBuildings(0);
Console.WriteLine(building.Name);


// access the first fruit in the terrain object.
IFruit fruit = world.GetFruits(0);
Console.WriteLine(fruit.Name);
```

Classes:

```
namespace Classes;

// Prove con il pattern Factory
// TerrainFactory classe principale per istanziare tutti gli altri oggetti 
contenuti in TerrainContainer

interface ITerrain
{
   // Metodi o proprietà comuni ai terreni ( colore , domensioni eccc) quindi classi che condividono questa interfaccia
   string Name { get; set; }

}


class TerrainFactory
{
    public static TerrainContainer CreateContainer<T>() where T : ITerrain
    {
        TerrainContainer container = new TerrainContainer();

        // Alcune operazioni specifiche per la creazione del contenitore, se necessario
        // esempio  if (typeof(T) == typeof(TerrainYellow))

        return container;
    }
}


class TerrainContainer
{
    // Create a list of objects with the interface 'ITerrain'.
    List<ITerrain> terrains = new List<ITerrain>();
    // Create a list of objects with the interface 'IBuilding'.
    List<IBuilding> buildings = new List<IBuilding>();
    // Create a list of objects with the interface 'IFruit'.
    List<IFruit> fruits = new List<IFruit>();


   public void AddTerrain(ITerrain terrain)
   {
       terrains.Add(terrain);
   }

   public ITerrain GetTerrain(int index)
   {
       return terrains[index];
   }


   public void AddBuilding(IBuilding building)
   {
       buildings.Add(building);
   }
 
   public IBuilding GetBuildings(int index)
   {
       return buildings[index];
   }


   public void AddFruits(IFruit fruit)
   {
       fruits.Add(fruit);
   }

   public IFruit GetFruits(int index)
   {
       return fruits[index];
   }
 }

class Terrain : ITerrain
{
    string name;
    public Terrain(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;   
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```